# Google Analytics working in debug view but not showing up in dashboard

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am having an issue where my analytics events for which I provide custom event name). The event names provided by Google works fine(Select_content,first_open,form_field_completion).  I am unable to see these events in the analytics dashboard or reports section. I see couple of events show some numbers but they are very low numbers. I am able to see the events go through in debug view when testing. Also I use Tag manager to enable debugging in debugView. I am clueless what is happening.
Also The analytics for iOS is showing up but not for Android